# Confused by javascript Keyboard events

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

I'm confused at how I'm supposed to handle keyboard events in Javascript. I'm trying to detect meta-z and meta-shift-z to implement undo/redo. What is currently working is to use

```
    let key = String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode);
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
      // Handle ctrl/cmd keypress
      if ((key === 'Z' && e.shiftKey) || key === 'Y') {
        // Ctrl/Cmd-shift Z or Cmd-Y => Redo
        redoGraph();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
      else if (key === 'Z') { // lower-case z, no shift
        // Ctrl/Cmd-Z => Undo
        undoGraph();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
```

However, both "which" and "keyCode" are deprecated. Though, as usual, the notice I found for the deprecation didn't say what to use instead. If I use "e.key", then according to W3Schools, Safari doesn't support that, so then it seems like I'd need to do both or something. Is there a best practice for detecting keyboard events?

Also, "e.key" always returns lower-case. So then if you wanted to detect typing, do you have to do your own manual conversion from lower to upper (including all diacritics, etc.)? Or is there a way to get a key event that says what the typed character should look like?

Comment: "_"e.key" always returns lower-case_", nope, it always returns the actual character, if you're pressing SHIFT down, and then hit A, `e.key` will return `A`, not `a`. According to MDN, Safari seems to support [event.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) too.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key